# script/server error `chdir': No such file or directory - project_folder/presents (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 2.3.18.

When running `rails server` by entering `ruby script/server`, I got this error:

```
Latitude-3540:/var/www/html/siteman$ ruby script/server

NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be
    removed on or after 2011-11-01.
        Gem.source_index called from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
        config.gem: Unpacked gem ihunter-whatcounts-0.4.0 in vendor/gems has a mismatched specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs'
    to fix this.
        /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in
    `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use
    String#encode instead.
        => Booting WEBrick
        => Rails 2.3.18 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
        config.load_paths is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths instead
        config.load_paths= is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths= instead
         [FSTR] Using Red Five FileStorage version 0.1
        /var/www/html/siteman/config/initializers/siteman.rb:23:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /var/www/html/siteman/presents
    (Errno::ENOENT)
            from /var/www/html/siteman/config/initializers/siteman.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in
    `load'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in
    `block in load_with_new_constant_marking'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in
    `new_constants_in'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in
    `load_with_new_constant_marking'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:622:in
    `block in load_application_initializers'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in
    `each'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in
    `load_application_initializers'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:176:in
    `process'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in
    `run'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in
    `require'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in
    `block in require'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in
    `new_constants_in'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in
    `require'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/config.ru:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in
    `instance_eval'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in
    `initialize'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/config.ru:1:in `new'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/config.ru:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:78:in
    `eval'
            from /var/www/html/siteman/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:78:in
    `<top (required)>'
            from script/server:3:in `require'
            from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: FYI Ruby 1.9.3 is deprecated: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/01/10/ruby-1-9-3-will-end-on-2015/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply .. But this is old project and need to run on ruby 1.9.3 so if you have any idea how to overcome this problem please suggest.

Comment: I am getting this error /var/www/html/siteman/config/initializers/siteman.rb:23:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /var/www/html/siteman/presents
    (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: `/var/www/html/siteman/config/initializers/siteman.rb` tries to go to directory `/var/www/html/siteman/presents` but this directory isn't there. 

If you add `/var/www/html/siteman/config/initializers/siteman.rb` to the question people could see what's going on in this line 23.

Comment: `Dir.chdir(Present.directory) do
  Dir.glob("*").each do |present|
    present_helpers = File.join(Present.directory, present, 'helpers')
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << present_helpers
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_once_paths.delete(present_helpers)
  end
end`

Comment: Well, `Present.directory` is configured to be `/var/www/html/siteman/presents`, and Rails tries to use some files from there, but this fails since the directory isn't available.
Now you have two options: 1# Find the module and put it into `/var/www/html/siteman/presents` or 2# got to where the directory is configured and change it to where the module is.

Comment: @MartinSchmidt Thank you..:)